# Change php echo message of a function using an html form?

Tags: php, forms, function, echo

I would like through a change the message html form a "php echo" I thought maybe there would be a way to edit the php file to display a message type or another as edit from the form. I would do it without having to make another request to a database.

The "echo" I want to change is this when you end the function that sends the data to the database.

```
if ($name){
$sql= "INSERT INTO box (name, mensaje) VALUES ('$name', '$mensaje')";   
mysqli_query($DB, $sql);

echo "All it uploaded correctly, but on Saturday, opening day,
 have to wait until an administrator validate the content. Thank you.";
}
```

Perhaps the question is silly, but I've never done something like and now I can not think how.

Would there be any way to edit the file "echo php" from a form? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the short answer is no. And from a security point of view that's a good thing. That is, you do not want anyone to be able to come along and edit your website from without.

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to vary the message that is echoed after your query. You could set up another page with a form that let's you securely configure the message that is to be displayed. You'd need to persist the message and retrieve it in your function prior to displaying it.